# Embed Google+ photos on website

Tags: google-plus, photos

Is it possible to embed Google+ photos on a website, much like it used to be possible with PicasaWeb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, Google's [PicasaWeb](https://picasaweb.google.com) and Google+ are always in sync. So if you have any image in Google+, you'll find it in PicasaWeb. From there you can get the code to embed the image and more.

Here is a sample code to embed one of the photos -

```
<table style="width:auto;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/m2Ne5aZLhC2RQfmtbw-8TtMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=embedwebsite">
                <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rNKwZkk5X68/Tg2cunuxA0I/AAAAAAAAAOM/-62AZtBNhd4/s144/threadlist-large.png" height="92" width="144" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-size:11px; text-align:right">
            From <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/100089984211197410017/20110701?authuser=0&feat=embedwebsite">2011-07-01</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The Picasa interface stopped working in the past few days. It now redirects to Google+ and there's no way I can see to embed photos any more.

Comment: If I go to picasaweb.google.com, it redirects to Google+ but after a few seconds "click here to go back to Picasa" appears on the top of the screen.